# How do I get the URL for a Google Sheets file that I just created using the copy function - google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my ongoing efforts to come to grips with google scripts:
I am trying to loop through a list of items in a sheet - wherever there is a "X" in column A, I want to copy my active file and then save the URL of the new file into my active file.  I've figured out most of it with the help of my second brain (otherwise known as google) and a helpful person on this forum, but I'm stuck on how to get the URL of the new file and save it to my sheet. While I'm at it, I'd also like to save the current date into column B of the same sheet.  Here is the code so far:

```
function LoopSaveSend() {

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("4 Week Cycle");
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = activeSheet.getLastColumn();

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Log");
  var lastSourceRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastSourceCol = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastSourceRow, lastSourceCol);
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();

  var activeRow = 0;

  //Loop through every retrieved row from the Source
  for (row in sourceData) {
    //IF Column A in this row has 'X', then work on it.
    if (sourceData[row][0] == 'X') {
      //Save it to a temporary variable
      var tempvalue = [sourceData[row][2]];
      activeSheet.getRange('rfInitials').setValue(tempvalue);
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var rffilename = spreadsheet.getRange('rfFileName').getValue();
      spreadsheet.copy(rffilename);
      var url = SpreadsheetApp.openById(rffilename).getUrl();
      sourceData[row][4].setValue(url);
      sourceData[row][0].setValue("")
   }
  }
}
```

It's the last 3 lines that aren't working (I don't even know if the last 2 rows will work because I haven't got that far yet.) The error I'm getting is that I need permission to open the file - but actually I don't want to open it - just want to get the URL.  Also - no code for getting the date yet... baby steps and all that.
Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the newly copied spreadsheet, change these two lines:

```
spreadsheet.copy(rffilename);
var url = SpreadsheetApp.openById(rffilename).getUrl();
```

to this single line:

```
var url = spreadsheet.copy(rffilename).getUrl()
```

The key here is that, per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname), the `copy` method

> Copies the spreadsheet and *returns the new one*.

So you can call `.getUrl()` directly on the result of `copy` to get the URL of the new copy.

The reason this line doesn't work as written:

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.openById(rffilename).getUrl();
```

is that `rffilename` is not a file id, it's a file name.  To use `.openById` you would need to know the file id of the new copy (which you could get with `spreadsheet.copy(rffilename).getId()` but in this case you don't need to).

You will also find that your last two lines don't work, as `.setValue` is a method of the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. You'll need to change these to something like

```
activeSheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(url);
activeSheet.getRange(row,0).setValue("")
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that got me very close to where I'm trying to go.  Firstly, I had to adjust the two rows that save the URL and clear column A to sourceSheet as it's the Log sheet that I'm recording the URL on. and I know the URL retrieval worked because it updated a cell in the log sheet, but unfortunately it updated a cell one row too high and one column to the left.  I understand this is because the index for my temporary array starts at 0 and the index for rows and columns starts at 1, so I adjusted the code to:

Comment: sourceSheet.getRange(row + 1,5).setValue(url);      sourceSheet.getRange(row + 1,1).setValue("");  (I'm used to VBA - that would have worked.)  The end result was that it does not save the URL or clear column A at all now.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  You might try changing `for (row in sourceData)` to `for (var row=0; row<sourceData.length; row++)`: in the former, it looks like JS considers the row indices as strings; the latter guarantees they are numbers.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.  Head explosion averted. :-)